# Listar más de 850000 registro de una tabla de SQLSERVER en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Espero puedan ayudarme con este problema.
No sé que recomendarán ustedes, pero yo estoy haciéndolo de esto modo.

El trabajo que estoy haciendo es comparar los de registros de un campo de la tabla que esta en SQLSERVER.

Ejemplo:

**Tabla_Guia**

`Campo_nombre_imagen` -> Este campo me devuelve el nombre de imagen de una guía.

`Fecha_guia` -> Este campo lo uso para mandarlo como parametro en mi `Store Procedure`.

```
Procedimiento Almacenado en SQLSERVER: 
alter proc  spSNMMan_Lista_Guia_x_mes_anno
@mes int,
@año int
as
select ltrim(g.GUIA_DET_NRO_REF) 'N° Guía'
from guia_detalle_nacional g WITH(NOLOCK)
where g.NWT_CON_IMG = 1 and
MONTH(guia_det_fch_emi)=@mes and
year(guia_det_fch_emi)=@año -------------> Yo se que esta tabla tiene más de 850000 registros.
```

En Visual Studio 2012 - C#

```
public DataTable Listar_Guias_x_parametros( int mes, int año)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    CD_Conexion cnx = new CD_Conexion();
    try
    {
        comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
        comando.CommandText = "spSNMMan_Lista_Guia_x_mes_anno";
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mes", mes);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@año", año);
        leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        tabla.Load(leer);
        return tabla;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conexion.CerrarConexion();
    }
}
```

---

Y en mi formulario realizo esto:

```
try
{
    CN_Guias guias = new CN_Guias();
    DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Today;
    string fecha_actual = Hoy.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    string mes, año;
    mes = txt_mes.Text;
    año = txt_anno.Text;
    string ruta = @"" + txt_ruta.Text + año + mes + "";
    String[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(ruta);
    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
    {
        string nom_img = dirs[i];
        string cadenaTexto = nom_img;
        String[] resultado = cadenaTexto.Split('\\');
        string ima_guia = resultado[resultado.Length - 1];
        string cadenaTexto2 = ima_guia;
        String[] resultado2 = cadenaTexto2.Split('.');
        string ima_guia2 = resultado2[resultado2.Length - 2];
        //*****************************************************************
        //AQUI VA EL OTRO FOR
        for (int o = 0; o < guias.Listar_Guias_x_parametros_prueba
                    (Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows.Count; o++)
        //{

        //for (int o = 0; o < guias.ListaPrueba().Rows.Count; o++)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(o));

            string x = guias.Listar_Guias_x_parametros_prueba
                (Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows[o][1].ToString();
            // guias.Listar_Guias_x_parametros_prueba
            //(Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows[o][1].ToString();
        }
        //*****************************************************************
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Me aparece un error de Tiempo de espera.
Pero cuando listo otra tabla de menos registros si funciona.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias.

Comment: Si ejecutas el mismo query en SQL Server solo, no desde el código ¿también da timeout? Sospecho que es el la parte de SQL no C#

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, trata de formatear la pregunta como corresponde

Comment: Hola Diego, en SqlServer si funciona. Pero demora bastante.

Comment: No logro imaginar para qué alguien querría traer esa cantidad de registros de la base de datos a un cliente. Recomiendo re-pensar el diseño. Si hay algo que hacer con los datos, procesalos en lotes más pequeños o directamente en el servidor.

Comment: Hola Jachguate, lo que sucede es que tenemos un sistema de digitalización de documentos(empresa Courier) e imaginarás que al mes realizan casi un millón de estos registros. Hubo casos donde en la base de datos figura que alguna guía tiene imagen escaneada pero en el servidor de archivos no existe. Entonces se requiere crear una pequeña aplicación que valide las imágenes de guías por mes y año. Si en caso una guía no tiene imagen, que se registre una fila en otra tabla con el número de guía. Espero haberme dejado entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al tener que filtrar por parte de fecha hace que el motor de base de datos tenga que recorrer todas las filas siempre, hay algunas mejoras que puedes aplicar a la tabla para que el query sea más rápido

1. De ser posible eliminar el componente de hora (si es que lo tienes)

   - Si no necesitas la hora en la fecha te conviene normalizar las fechas, es decir si la columna datetime guardas `2018-10-01 10:23:31.123` cambiar a `2018-10-01 00:00:00.000`.  Esto ayudará en el siguiente punto.
2. Agregar un índice a la columna de fecha

   - Al indexar la columna el motor realizará una búsqueda en un espacio más reducido en lugar de toda la tabla, esto a cambio de ocupar más espacio por la tabla.

     ```
     CREATE INDEX idx_guia_detalle_nacional_fecha ON guia_detalle_nacional(guia_det_fch_emi)
     ```
3. Hacer el query por rango en lugar de extraer las partes de la fecha

   - Para poder aprovechar el nuevo índice tienes que cambiar la manera en que haces el query, comparar como rango de datetime en lugar de por mes y año:

     ```
     alter proc spSNMMan_Lista_Guia_x_mes_anno @mes int, @año int as 

     declare @inicioMes datetime =  cast(@año as varchar) + '-' + cast(@mes as varchar) + '-' + '1'

     select ltrim(g.GUIA_DET_NRO_REF) 'N° Guía' 
     from guia_detalle_nacional g with(nolock) 
     where g.NWT_CON_IMG = 1
     and guia_det_fch_emi >= @inicioMes
     and guia_det_fch_emi < dateadd(month, 1, @inicioMes)
     ```

Comment: Hola Diego, disculpa. No me queda claro el procedimiento almacenado. Podrás detallarme un poco más.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no queda claro, como funciona?

Comment: Error en esta linéa: declare @inicioMes datetime = concat(@año, format(@mes, '0#'), '01')

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error? eso es lo más importante :)

Comment: Por ejemplo: realice lo del INDEX, corri la prueba en SQL SERVER y la velocidad del listado es un 80% más rápido, más no en el C#. Aun me muestra el mensaje de Tiempo de espera.

Comment: Probablemente el error en esa línea es porque la función `FORMAT` está disponible a partir de SQL Server 2012.  ¿Qué versión usas? Deberías indicar si usas una versión antigua.

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta en esa línea, prueba con eso.

Comment: Olvide comentar eso: version Sql Server 2008 R2.

Comment: ejecute  y resulto esto: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure spSNMMan_Lista_Guia_x_mes_anno, Line 3
'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure spSNMMan_Lista_Guia_x_mes_anno, Line 8
Must declare the scalar variable "@inicioMes".

Comment: Vaya, `CONCAT` tampoco está disponible en esa versión. En lugar de eso usa la concatenación antigua con `+`.

Comment: OK, ya modifique todo eso. Ahora voy a correo la aplicación desde el C# para ver pasar esa parte del listado. Este es mi codigo para realizar la comparación de nombres. Aqui la lista de errores que me sale. https://upcedupe-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/u201600668_upc_edu_pe/EhOA1H-kKc1Ltu7625sXCYoB6AIOnRq5m-dC7hQFqirZcQ?e=i3EThI